# Private Object Field in Django Admin

Tags: python-3.x, django, templates, django-admin

I'm wondering what the best way to have an editable field (by admins) for some object in Django admin that can't be viewable on the public site. For example, a notes section for content authors with conventions or instructions that a front-end dev can't accidentally render in a template.

Something like:

```
class SomeModel(Model):
    internal_notes = CharField(max_length=1024, public=False)
```

So some object, `o`, ***can't*** be rendered in a public (non-admin) template:

```
{{ o.internal_notes }}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible, I assume Django admin has to do {{ o.internal_notes }} to access the field so blocking it won't be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are right, but I think there is a way with permissions. Perhaps the object can be viewed only by "staff"... I'm working on something, so I'll post here if/when I get it working.